# Do i need to use grunt with angularjs 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, gruntjs

i have a project in angular 4 and when i run the ng serve it automatically creates the bundle of the files so in that case Do i need to use grunt in my project ?

Comment: I haven't used Angular 4 myself, but based on my understanding, Grunt is just a task runner. Anything you can do with Grunt, Gulp can also handle. As long as you have access to the source files, you should also be able to use a bundler like Webpack or Browserify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't, if you're using Angular Cli then that's all you need. You can use task runners for other bits like deploying etc but for the building and running of Angular - the CLI has it all.

Comment: so when i go to production i dont need to do anything regarding minifications etc ?

Comment: Indeed it does it for you, check this page out https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Answer (score 0):

angular 2 and angular 4 manages this thing already, but through angular-cli. some of the files already use the main.js and polyfill.js etc.

Comment: see this above text